# Logback and JsonLayout: can't pass custom fields

Tags: spring, logging, logback, logback-classic

I have this configuration in my logback.xml into a Spring Web Application (NO Spring Boot).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

     <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">             
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
                <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX</timestampFormat>
                <timestampFormatTimezoneId>Etc/UTC</timestampFormatTimezoneId>              
                <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                    <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
                </jsonFormatter>
            </layout>            
            <customFields>{"appname":"foobar"}</customFields>            
        </encoder>                    
    </appender>

    <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

The JSON layout works fine but custom fields as "appname": "foobar" are not printed:

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2020-06-10T14:55:25.534Z",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "thread" : "Catalina-utility-1",
  "logger" : "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet",
  "message" : "FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 72 ms",
  "context" : "default"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**SOLUTION**

I was using the wrong libraries for my needs:

- logback-jackson
- logback-json-classic

Because of the fact that I need to process logs through Logstash I've corrected my configuration like this:

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
                <version>6.4</version>
            </dependency>
```

logback.xml

```
<appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <customFields>{"customer":"X", "appname":"Y", "environment":"dev"}</customFields>            
        </encoder>    
    </appender>
```

and now It works fine.

Comment: Have you been able to get _dynamic_ properties added to your JSON records?

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled this question because I had the same problem, and I found a solution, with `logback-jackson` and `logback-json-classic`.

**Option 1: Per-Thread via Mapped Diagnostic Context (`MDC`)**

SLF4j's Mapped Diagnostic Context is a per-thread key-value store that we can use to write custom structured data to the log output.

```
MDC.put("customKey", "customValue");
```

Logback's `JsonLayout` will automatically print this value under a special `mdc` JSON object without any further configuration.

```
{ [...], "mdc": {"customKey", "customValue"}}
```

Note that the `MDC` is constructed per thread and if it is empty, no `mdc` field is printed to the log output.

**Option 2: Global (for all threads)**

If you want custom fields to appear at the JSON output's root, you need to create a custom, but simple Layout class that extends `JsonLayout`. `JsonLayout` provides us with a `addCustomDataToJsonMap` we can override.

```
package com.mypackage;

import ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout;

public class CustomJsonLayout extends JsonLayout {

  @Override
  protected void addCustomDataToJsonMap(Map<String, Object> map, ILoggingEvent event) {
    map.put("customKey", "customValue");
  }
}
```

Now, you just need to tell Logback to use `CustomJsonLayout` instead of `JsonLayout` in your `logback.xml` file and keep the rest the same.

```
<layout class="com.mypackage.CustomJsonLayout">
    ...
</layout>
```

Now, any log message will have the following output:

```
{ ..., "customKey": "customValue"}
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to add custom fields to the root of the message that are defined in each class that logs? For instance, for a service class I want a field "parameters" and its value be a map<string, string> to log the parameters that resulted in an exception. Then I'd like another field called "exception" and be able to keep the exception in its own field. In a utility class, I want to a field called "processTime". So just little bits of data that I can use for observability, and makes searching logs easier. I've seen in done before,  but using a splunk appender in l4j.